# How to send mulitple radio groups value from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is a add to cart system. now i can send quantity with id. but i want to send radio groups values also.. how do this
here is my codes

product.php

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {

$('.popbutton').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var qtyValue = $("input[type='text'][name='qty']").val();
    var radio = $("input[type='radio'][name='answer[]']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
            id: id,
            quantityValue : qtyValue, 
            radioValue : radio
        },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (html) {
            $('body').append(html);
            $(html).bPopup();
        },
        error: function (returnValue) {}
    });
});


});
</script>
```

my radio groups in product.php

```
Capacity:
<label><input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="8"> 8 GB </label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="4"> 4 GB </label><br />
Type:
<label><input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="sony"> Sony </label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="samsung"> Samsung </label>

<input id="qty" type="text" class="w30" name="qty" size="2" value="1" /><br />

<button id="button-cart" class="popbutton" data-id="40">Add to Cart</button>
```

ajax.php

```
$answers = $_POST['radioValue'];

foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    echo $answer;
//not work
}
```

Comment: it would be easier if you enclose all of your `inputs` inside a `form` then sending them through `ajax` with `data : $('YOUR-FORM').serialize()`

Comment: @roullie please give me full code as answer.. thanks

Comment: by this approach you can get all the get all the radio button value put them in a string pass it as data to ajax and do the same at the server php

Comment: `please give me full code as answer` SO will not do your homework for you. you were given the way to do it. do it yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

```
*var datastring = $("#contactForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your url.php",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // do what ever you want with the server response
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error handing here');
            }
        });*
```

Comment: you have to answer twice?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose all your needed inputs inside a form

```
    <form id="yourForm" onsubmit="return false;">
        Capacity:
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="8"> 8 GB </label><br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="4"> 4 GB </label><br />
        Type:
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="sony"> Sony </label><br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="samsung"> Samsung </label>

        <input id="qty" type="text" class="w30" name="qty" size="2" value="1" /><br />

        <button id="button-cart" class="popbutton" data-id="40">Add to Cart</button>
    </form>
```

Then your javascript

```
    $('.popbutton').on('click', function () {
        var data = $('#yourForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: data,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (html) {
                $('body').append(html);
                $(html).bPopup();
            },
            error: function (returnValue) {}
        });
    });
```

You can access your radio values on ajax.php by

```
    print_r($_POST['answer']);
```

Comment: how to send `data-id="40"` from add to cart button? its not work